# What is wrong with this python code??? Please show me how to fix it

Tags: python

```
building = [["Farm","-1","0","F","1","1","-1"],
            ["Plot","0","0","P","1","0","-1"],
            ["House","20","4","H","0","0","5"]]

cmd = input(">")
if (cmd == "build"):
      c = 0
      length = len(building)
      while (c < length):
        bu = building(c)
        print(c + ") " + bu[0])
        c = c + 1
```

Please help!

By the way, using `e = sys.exc_info()` I get:

```
(<class 'TypeError'>, TypeError("'builtin_function_or_method' object is not
subscriptable",), <traceback object at 0x7f3393e23d88>)
```

Comment: Please share more code. And what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: What is `building`? Can you share more of the stack trace?

Comment: Whats in building?   Try print(type(building))

Comment: Ill share more code. i'm trying to make a city building game, and i want to list all the buildings.

Comment: You have other errors in this code beyond the one describe above, e.g. `building(c)` - assume you meant `building[c]`. And `c + ") "`, c is an int and you can't add it to a string. Fixing those errors, the code works fine and doesn't lead to the TypeError above.

Comment: The entire thing of e = sys.exc_info() is:  (<class 'TypeError'>, TypeError("'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable",), <traceback object at 0x7fa09145adc8>)

Comment: I've just replaced `building(c)` with `building[c]`, and replaced `print(c + ") " + bu[0])` with `print(str(c) + ") " + str(bu[0]))`. Then this works. And where is `e = sys.exc_info()`?

Comment: it still errors, here, why dont i paste the ENTIRE CODE. into it!

Comment: @ZacharyJohnson, see my answer. If you want, just paste the full code here.

Comment: If it errors, it's not in this section of code (after the fixes described). Try not catching the exception and see what is printed out on exit or if you must catch it. `import traceback; traceback.print_exc()`

Answer (score 0):

Here you have your fixed code:

```
building = [ ["Farm","-1","0","F","1","1","-1"], ["Plot","0","0","P","1","0","-1"], ["House","20","4","H","0","0","5"]]
cmd = input(">")

if (cmd == "build"):
      c = 0
      length = len(building)
      while (c < length):
            bu = building[c]
            print(str(c) + ") " + bu[0])
            c = c + 1
```

**What was fixed:**

- Indents

- Calling list building - () instead of []

- str(c) in print, since c is an int and you can't sum ints and strings

Also, `import sys` before using `e = sys.exc_info()`

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! i imported a python file that used the same name as a function!